# Access a single key from AWS Secret in apprunner.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-app-runner

I am trying to deploy to apprunner via apprunner.yaml

I have stored two key value pairs in single AWS secret.

ARN: xxxx
Under this, there are `key1:value1` and `key2:value`
How can access these keys as env variables in apprunner.yaml. `key1` env variable should have `value1` as value and so on..

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/config-file-examples.html

This above page has some examples. But it doesn't say how to access different key value pairs stored under same secret.

My current yaml file

```
runtime: python311
build:
  commands:
    build:
      - pip install -r requirements.txt
run:
  runtime-version: 3.11.7
  command: sh hello.sh
  network:
    port: 8000
```

Thank you!

I am pretty new to App Runner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accessed like

```
 secrets:
    - name: secret1
      value-from: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:testingstackAppRunnerConstr-kJFXde2ULKbT-S7t8xR:key1::"
```